# Flipping a 3 sided coin

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python language and I'm currently working on a problem regarding the flipping of a 3 sided coin as in Heads, Tails and Other side. Here's my code:

```
import random
x= int(input("How many times would you flip a coin?:"))
head = 0
tail = 0
other = 0
for i in range(x):
    p = random.randrange(0,2)
    if p<=0.3:
       print("It is head")
       head = head + 1
    elif (p>0.3 and p<=0.6):
       print("It is tail")
       tail = tail + 1
    else:
       print("It is other")
       other = other + 1

print("The total number of head is",head)
print("The total number of tail is",tail)
print("The total number of other is",other)
```

We are asked to explore on the random.randrange function so I'm not sure if i have done that part right. The program does execute however i realise that only either head and tail is produced where as the other face doesn't seem to be produced by the program. :)

Comment: I will make it `random.randrange(0,3)` and then have the if-else w.r.t. `1`, & `2`, i.e. the ranges 0-1, 1-2, 2-3. Also, just use `head += 1` instead of `head = head + 1`.

Comment: Don't use ranges (e.g. 0-1): the values are integers. You can just do `if p == 1:`.

Comment: Part of the "exploration" you're supposed to do surely involves reading the documentation (or your textbook) and doing your own debugging?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using randrange correctly. You should experiment with it at the interpreter and check the Python documentation. You will find that `randrange(0,2)` returns a random value from `range(0, 2)`, and `range(0, 2)` only contains the values 0 and 1. The p values you're checking against, e.g. p <= 0.3, make no sense in this context. One way of fixing it would be:

```
p = random.randrange(0, 3)
if p == 0:
    do stuff
else if p == 1:
    do other stuff
else:
    do other other stuff
```